# Singly linked list iteration complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, list, time-complexity

First of all, my basic understanding of a singly linked list has been that every node only points to the next subsequent node, so my problem might stem from the fact that my definition of such list is incorrect.

Given the list setup, getting to node *n* would require iterating through *n-1* nodes that come before it, so search and access would be O(n). Now, apparently node insertion and deletion take O(1), but unless they are talking about first item insertion, then in reality it would be O(n) + O(1) for you to insert the item between nodes *n* and *n+1*.

Now, indexing a list would also have O(n) complexity, yet apparently building such indexes is frowned upon, and I cannot understand why. Couldn't we build a singly linked list index, which would allow us true O(1) insertion and deletion without having to perform an O(n) iteration over the list to get to our specific node? It wouldn't even need to be an index of all nodes, and we could have it pointing to subindexes i.e. for a list of 1000 items, first index would point to 10 different indexes for items between 1-100, 101-200, etc. and then those indexes could point to smaller indexes that go by 10. This way getting to node 543 could potentially take only 3+(index traversal) iterations, instead of 543 as it would for a typical singly linked list.

I guess, what I am asking is why such indexing should typically be avoided?

Answer (score 5):

You are describing a [**skip-list**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

A skip list have a search, insert, delete time complexity of `O(logN)`, since this "smaller subindexes" you describe - you have logarithmic number of them (what happens if your list has 100 elements? How many of these levels do you need? And how much for 1,000,000 elements? and 10^30?).

Note that a skip list is usually maintained sorted, but you can do it unsorted (which is sorted by index - actually) if you wish as well.

Answer (score 2):

With a singly-linked list, even if you already have a direct reference to the node to **delete**, the complexity is not O(1). This is because you have to update the *prior* node's next-node reference, which requires you to iterate through the list -- resulting in O(N) complexity. To get O(1) complexity for deletion, you'd need a doubly-linked list.

There is already a collections class that combines a HashMap with a doubly-linked list: the [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).